# Email server doesn't resolve external DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, email, email-server

The setup: I have a hosting, linked to example1.com. Inside, I have a domain as example2.com with its website. The mailing of example2.com is handled by mx.example3.com (example3 is outside of my server).

The problem: user@example1.com cannot email user@example2.com, because when trying to resolve the DNS never gets outside the server, and I receive an automated email saying that user@example2.com is not found.

My suggestion: It never gets outside of my server because in my server example2.com it is found, but we don't handle the email services, so nothing is found. Emailing from Gmail to example2.com works as expected.

My solution didn't work: I configured the DNS record on my example2.com domain as:
MX example2.com 10 mx.example3.com
I thought that should work but it didn't.

Any idea in mind?

**SOLUTION**
Even this is not the best, we just deactivated the e-mail service for that domain and now works properly.

Thank you for your ideas.

Comment: You've configured it wrong. Try configuring it right instead. (For any more exact answers, you'd need to include at least the bare minimum of configuration information.)

Comment: Your solution is *exactly* what I recommended below. Please accept my answer as correct if it helped you.

Answer (score 4):

The mailserver on your hosted server thinks that mail for `example2.com` is supposed to be delivered locally, so it never looks up the MX record for it. You'll need to modify your MTA's configuration to remove this configuration.